# allow singleQuote and backtick in eslint

Tags: eslint, prettier

I need to use only **signleQuote** and **backTick** in the eslint .

These are my codes in the json file :

```json
"rulse":{
    "quotes": "error",
    "jsx-quotes": [2, "prefer-single"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a misspelling and you must tell eslint what quotes to use:

```json
"rules": {
   "quotes": ["error", "single", "avoid-escape"]
}
```